# How can I make a graphics path with more points?

Tags: c#, curve

I'm creating a path that will be followed by a rectangle. I want to make it with more "tick" points, since on each timer tick I draw it on the next point on the made curve. When it reaches the curve's turn, it goes smoothly, since there are more points at the curve, but at the straight parts of the path, it skips a lot of distance to reach the next points on the list. How can I make the PathPoints with more points? Or is there a better approach to what I'm trying to do? The approach that I'm using, I found it on the internet.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //avoid flickering
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        //make a bitmap to display
        _bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aquamarine, new Rectangle(_bmp.Width / 2 - 2, _bmp.Height / 2 - 2, 10, 10));
        }

        //cleanup
        this.FormClosing += delegate { if (_bmp != null) _bmp.Dispose(); if (_gPath != null) _gPath.Dispose(); };

        //setup a path and add some random values
        _gPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

        List<Point> fList = new List<Point>();

        //add points that will let the picturebox be fully visible inside the form
        Point middle = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2);
        fList.Add(new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height));
        fList.Add(new Point(middle.X - 20, middle.Y + 20));
        fList.Add(new Point(0, this.ClientSize.Height / 2));
        //fList.Add(new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2));

        //add a curve by these values
        _gPath.AddCurve(fList.ToArray());

        //flatten, to make the path a Path of lines and points
        _gPath.Flatten();

        //get these points as Array to locate the picturebox
        this._points = _gPath.PathPoints;

        //add the handler for the paint-event
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);

        //start the timer
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Interval = 100;
        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(_points.Length);
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (_gPath != null && _bmp != null)
        {
            //draw the image
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, _gPath);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bmp, (int)_points[_i].X - (_bmp.Width / 2), (int)_points[_i].Y - (_bmp.Height / 2));
        }
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Stop();

        //redraw
        this.Invalidate();

        _i++;
        if (_i >= _points.Length)
            _i = 0;

        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To make more points you should overload for Flatten method:

```
_gPath.Flatten(null, (float) 0.1);
```

Also I would recommend to organize Animation loop to have interval of 40ms. So it would be 25 frames per second. (1000s / 25 = 40 ms)

```
t.Interval = 40;
```